# android - download base64 encoded pdf file and open it

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a solution to simply download a base64 encoded pdf file of a webservice and open it with an preinstalled pdf viewer. My application targets `Android R`. I tried something like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) but I dont't want a picker to open.

This is my code so far. It is just downloading the file and converts it to a bytearray. The next step should by saving the file and opening it.

```
  lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {

                    Snackbar.make(binding.root, getString(R.string.load_document_started), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    
                    val documentData = DocumentDao().get(document.id, montageOrder)
                    val docAsByte = Base64.decode(documentData.data, Base64.DEFAULT)

                    val currentDateString  = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

                    val fileName = document.documentType.
                    lowercase()
                        .replace("ä", "ae")
                        .replace("ü", "ue")
                        .replace("ö", "oe") +
                     "_" + currentDateString

                               val file = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName)
                    val fileStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    fileStream.write(docAsByte)
                    fileStream.close()


                    val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf")
                    target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

                    val intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Yolo");
                    startActivity(intent)


                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Dokument konnte nicht geladen werden: " + e.message, e)
                    Snackbar.make(binding.root, getString(R.string.exception_could_not_load_document), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
```

This results in a `FileUriExposedException`

Another aproach was using the SAF

```
    lateinit var docAsByte : ByteArray

private val createFileLauncher = registerForActivityResult(CreatePdfDocument()) { uri ->

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val stream = requireContext().contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)
            stream?.write(docAsByte)
            stream?.close()

            val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
            target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

            startActivity(target)
        }
    }


}


private fun setGui() {
    _binding?.lvDocuments?.adapter = DocumentAdapter(requireContext(), montageOrder.documents)
    _binding?.lvDocuments?.setOnItemClickListener  { parent, _, position, _ ->
        val document : Document =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as Document

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {

                    val currentDateString  = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

                    val fileName = document.documentType.
                    lowercase()
                        .replace("ä", "ae")
                        .replace("ü", "ue")
                        .replace("ö", "oe") +
                            "_" +
                            montageOrder.orderNumber +
                            "_" +
                            currentDateString +
                            ".pdf"

                    Snackbar.make(binding.root, getString(R.string.load_document_started), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    val documentData = DocumentDao().get(document.id, montageOrder)
                    docAsByte = Base64.decode(documentData.data, Base64.DEFAULT)


                    createFileLauncher.launch(fileName)

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Dokument konnte nicht geladen werden: " + e.message, e)
                    Snackbar.make(binding.root, getString(R.string.exception_could_not_load_document), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except for opening. But if I open the pdf via file explorer it works.

Comment: What is the problem saving the bytes in that byte array to file?

Comment: i edited the post with an approach of me. it results in a FileUriExposedException.

Comment: That code is nearly ok. I can tell you why you get a FileUriExposedException but you could google it as hundreds before you got it. Me too when i got an Android 7/N device.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a thread online and solved it this way: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/614761

Add provider_paths.xml to xml resource folder

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

In your manifest add a FileProvider:

```
 <application>
    <provider
         android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
         android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
         android:exported="false"
         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
     </provider>
 </application>
```

Prepare to download files to any directory your app owns, such as getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir(), getCacheDir() or getExternalCacheDir().

```
val privateDir = context.getFilesDir()
```

Download file taking its progress into account (DIY):

```
val downloadedFile = myFancyMethodToDownloadToAnyDir(url, privateDir, fileName)
```

Copy it to Downloads folder:

```
private val DOWNLOAD_DIR = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

val finalUri : Uri? = copyFileToDownloads(context, downloadedFile)

fun copyFileToDownloads(context: Context, downloadedFile: File): Uri? {
    val resolver = context.contentResolver
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, getName(downloadedFile))
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, getMimeType(downloadedFile))
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, getFileSize(downloadedFile))
        }
        resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
    } else {
        val authority = "${context.packageName}.provider"
        val destinyFile = File(DOWNLOAD_DIR, getName(downloadedFile))
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, destinyFile)
    }?.also { downloadedUri ->
        resolver.openOutputStream(downloadedUri).use { outputStream ->
            val brr = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(downloadedFile.absoluteFile))
            while ((bufferedInputStream.read(brr, 0, brr.size).also { len = it }) != -1) {
                outputStream?.write(brr, 0, len)
            }
            outputStream?.flush()
            bufferedInputStream.close()
        }
    }
```

Once in download folder you can open file from app like this:

```
val authority = "${context.packageName}.provider"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    setDataAndType(finalUri, getMimeTypeForUri(finalUri))
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    } else {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
}
try {
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, chooseAppToOpenWith))
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error opening file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

//Kitkat or above
fun getMimeTypeForUri(context: Context, finalUri: Uri) : String =
    DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, finalUri)?.type ?: "application/octet-stream"

//Just in case this is for Android 4.3 or below
fun getMimeTypeForFile(finalFile: File) : String =
    DocumentFile.fromFile(it)?.type ?: "application/octet-stream"
```